# LicenseMemo displays plain texts after changing Parent to CustomForm

Tags: inno-setup

I have created Custom Form (`CreateCustomForm`) and changed `LicenseMemo.Parent` to this Form. 
Unfortunately that results quite not as expected as the `LicenseFile` RTF is always displayed as Plain Text - all RTF formatting is gone (Font, Font Styles, Font Sizes, etc.).

Should I set additional formatting for LicenseMemo after changing it's parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because when you are re-parenting a control, the control's window is internally re-created and since the [`TRichEditViewer`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-5_5_4/Components/RichEditViewer.pas#L25) component doesn't store the RTF stream anyhow, nor reload it when the control is being recreated, it simply loses its RTF content and shows only plain text which stored is.

What is also bad for this case is that even the [`RTFText`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-5_5_4/Components/RichEditViewer.pas#L42) property doesn't implement reading of the RTF stream from existing control instance, so you cannot even save the RTF by yourself before re-parenting for restoring it later on.

There is a way to get the RTF stream by using [`EM_STREAMOUT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774304%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message, but that's a quite a lot of work which might finally be untranslatable for Inno Setup Pascal Script due to lack of missing pointer support.

The only easy workaround I can think of is to reload the RTF content file after re-parenting the control. I know that you'll need to include the license file into `[Files]` entries and extract it manually, but it's the least painful way to go.

Comment: Worth trying. Thank you for clue.

Comment: You're welcome! Well, the best would of course be if the `TRichEditViewer` control at least before re-creating temporarily store the RTF stream and restore it after re-creating, so it wouldn't forget the RTF anymore.

Comment: I have `LoadStringFromFile` and then passed it to `WizardForm.LicenseMemo.RTFText`

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I would think of when talking about manual loading. However, it would be great if the `RTFText` property would be readable and return the RTF string for you.